# Unity 2d Movement script issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 2d, sprite

So I'm making a 2d platformer in Unity, (Still new to c# and Unity as well), and I'm trying to make a movement script for a simple square, and the square will randomly stop moving, and I'll have to jump to start moving again, only for it to happen once more.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpHeight;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, jumpHeight);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is likely due to the collider on the object. Is the object placed on a 'ground' ? Does your script work if there is no ground (and gravity is disabled) ?

Comment: Your code is incomplete `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = 
 new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x,` which leads me to believe this isn't the exact code being used. Please provide the exact code. There doesn't seem to be any functionality mistakes in this code. Like @Bejasc noted, it's likely a bump in the ground, make sure the ground is or try it with a sphere-shaped collider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is likely in the comments, by @Bejasc, provided you've provided us with the actual code being used. Here's some tips you didn't ask for to improve your code in terms of cleanliness, best practice and some functionality:

1. Don't use GetComponent<>() every time you want to read a value. Save it in a variable when the GameObject is created! (Check the Start()-method in code below)
2. You set Y-velocity to 0 if the player is moving, this will not work if you want to jump and move at the same time, if you jump (setting the Y velocity to jumpHeight) then move (setting the Y velocity to 0) your character will float mid air since we set Y-velocity to 0 every frame. Set it to the current Y-velocity instead! (Check the y parameter in the `new Vector2` when moving)

---

Resulting code:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpHeight;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }
}
```

---

For this simple movement script you could also simplify the movement code a bunch by doing:

(provided you're using standard Input settings in Unitys input settings (Edit -> Project settings -> Input))

Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") will be `-1` if `A`, `left arrow` or `left on a gamepad joystick` is pressed and `1` if `D`, `right arrow` or `right on a gamepad joystick` is pressed. This is the default settings for "Horizontal" and I guess you can guess what "Vertical" does.

```
void Update() {
    float moveDir = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDir, rb.velocity.y);

    // Your jump code:
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have questions or if this was helpful at all.

Comment: Okay, so now I know it was a problem with the collider, because I switched to a circle collider and it worked, however, it produces shaky movement. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Could you describe the issue in a bit more details? Shaky how? Up and down? Shaky in speed? You're using physics to move your ball, if the surface it is sliding on is shaky, its movement will be shaky.

Comment: I will check tonight. was not able to check last night.

Comment: The movement from the character itself is shaking, lightly.

Comment: Any fixes? I've been trying different techniques, but nothing so far.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot help you with this little information. From what you've showed me there are nothing indicating a shaky movement.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've gotten this to work is to change the fixed timestep to 0.0166 in the Time manager. Seems the Physics engine and Update are not in sync with the result a stutter.

Answer (score 0):

I made a basic script for 2d movement. Feel free to take notes or copy and paste.

```
void Update()
{
    // check for the a key to be pressed
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        // add velocity to the player
        rb.velocity += (Vector2.left * (speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }

    // check for the d key to be pressed
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        // add velocity to the player
        rb.velocity += (Vector2.right * (speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```